# Swift cannot find overload when generics involved

Tags: swift, generics, overload-resolution

I have the following code:

```
protocol MyEnum {

}

class MyClass {
    func append(_ value: UInt8) {
        print("uint8 \(value)")
    }

    func append(_ value: UInt16) {
        print("uint16 \(value)")
    }

    func append<T: MyEnum>(_ value: T) {
        print("myenum \(value)")
    }
}

let c = MyClass()

func appendAny<T>(_ value: T) {
    switch value {
    case let u8 as UInt8:
        c.append(u8)
    case let u16 as UInt16:
        c.append(u16)
    case let myenum as MyEnum:
        c.append(myenum)
    default:
        assert(false)
    }
}
```

The error is reported by the compiler for the line `c.append(myenum)` stating

> Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type (MyEnum)

Please, explain to me why this happens and what is the correct solution in this case. I want to preserve my overloads, since when called with a concrete `MyEnum` instance, all works fine.

Comment: This is another variant of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself: A protocol does not conform to itself. Change the third variant to     `func append(_ value: MyEnum)`  to make it compile.

Comment: Thank you @MartinR that worked. I guess I've overengineered that generic ```append``` method a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Martin noted in his comment, you should change your final `append()` overload to be:

```
func append(_ value: MyEnum) {
    print("myenum \(value)")
}
```

Because you want to treat the value as "an instance of a protocol", not an "instance of a concrete type that happens to conform to the protocol". An instance that has a protocol *type* is not *also* a concrete type that conforms to that protocol.

Another note: since you aren't really using generic constraints or any compile-time properties of the type `T` (only runtime casting), why not just change `appendAny` to be:

```
func appendAny(_ value: Any) {
    switch value {
    case let u8 as UInt8:
        c.append(u8)
    case let u16 as UInt16:
        c.append(u16)
    case let myenum as MyEnum:
        c.append(myenum)
    default:
        assert(false)
    }
}
```